# On/off subscription attribute for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have an app that can sign up a new subscriber. When they sign up the user is subscribed for one year, I want to make a way of saying "if the year is up your subscription is now turned off until renewal". I recently added a attribute to subscriber called `status` and I set it to a string. My thought is that I could make a if/else statement that would condition either on or off for the subscriber but I'm not sure if that's the best idea? My question is - What is the best way to handle a case like this? I'll post some code for clarity.

CONTROLLER:

```
   class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

  def index
    @search = Subscriber.search(params[:q])
    @subscriber = @search.result
    @search.build_condition if @search.conditions.empty?
    @search.build_sort if @search.sorts.empty?
  end

  def new
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
  end

  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.create(subscriber_params)
    if @subscriber.save
      flash[:notice] = "Subscriber Has Been Successfully Created"
      redirect_to new_subscriber_path(:subscriber)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

SCHEMA:

```
    create_table "subscribers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "phone_number"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.integer  "visit"
    t.integer  "mug_number"
    t.string   "status"
  end
```

As you can see everything is pretty basic. I'm just looking mainly for advice on how to handle this situation. any help would be great thanks!

Comment: You may want to look into cron and [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) for scheduling "unsubscribe" code to be run at the end of the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `status` is not enough. You need the subscription date.

**Schema**

```
create_table "subscribers", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "phone_number"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  t.integer  "visit"
  t.integer  "mug_number"
  t.date     "subscription_date"  # We don't neet status any more
end

# If you want to use subscription_date in the active way (see below)
add_index :subscribers, :subscription_date
```

And you can define a method to tell whether a user is still subscribing.

You can also add a [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to your model class.

**Model**

```
class Subscriber
  scope :subscribing, -> {where subscription_date > 1.year.ago}
  scope :non_subscribing, -> {where.not subscription_date > 1.year.ago}

  def subscribing?
    !!(subscription_date && subscription_date > 1.year.ago)
  end
end
```

You have 2 ways to use this state.

### The passive (easy) way

In this way, you just tell the user that his/her subscription is end (or will come to an end soon).

**somewhere in your view**

```
<% unless @subscriber.subscribing? %>
<p>Your subscription is now turned off.</p>
<% end %>
```

If the user doesn't visit your site, nothing happens.

### The active way

You will have a scheduler that fetches non_subscribing users everyday and send them notifications (email, sms or mobile push).

You can use the gem [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) as your scheduler.

**config/schedule.rb**

```
every :day, at: '20:30' do
  rake 'notify_subscription_expiration'
end
```

**lib/tasks/subscription.rake**

```
task :notify_subscription_expiration => : environment do
  Subscriber.non_subscribing.find_each do |subscriber|
    # send notification
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! @Aetherus. I just have one question. How should I go about setting the subscription_date?  Something like `on_create`? Do you get one I mean... like right now if someone subscribes the `subscription_date` is nil.

Comment: @CameronBass  `subscriber.subscription_date = Time.now` in the controller or in the model using `before_create`: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#creating-an-object

Comment: @CameronBass or `before_save` but only set if `nil`, like `subscriber.subscription_date ||= Time.now`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest we have an attribute like `expired_at:datetime` to specify when the subscription is expired.

Okay now it is easy to know a subscriber is expired or not

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :expired, -> { where('expired_at > ?', Time.now }
end
```

The remaining concern is how to calculate `expired_at`, it is quite easy, isn't it? We can implement a callback in model like

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :expired, -> { where('expired_at > ?', Time.now }
  before_create :calculate_expired_at

  private

  def calculate_expired_at
     # If expired_at is not specified, make it expired 1 year after now
     self.expired_at ||= Time.now + 1.year
  end
end
```

This is kinda flexible because someday you change your strategy like 2 years subscription, this solution can still handle this situation!

Additionally, to make a subscriber expired, it couldn't be easier, just assign `expired_at = Time.now`!

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**

Here's a solution using the code provided in the question. Refactor as needed according to best practices and conventions.

1) Add `/expired` route, which renders text. It could be changed to point at a view.

```
# config/routes.rb
get "expired" => "subscribers#expired", :as => :expired
```

---

2) Add `before_filter` that checks for an authenticated subscriber on every request, by checking if `subscriber` is populated. I assumed `subscriber` is equivalent to `current_user`.

`check_for_subscription` checks if subscription is valid and if not updates `subscriber.status` with `"expired"`, then redirects to `/expired` page.

If `subscriber.status` already is `"expired"`, the filter will redirect straight to `/expired` page.

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :check_for_subscription

  def check_for_subscription
    if subscriber
      case subscriber.status

      when "subscribed" then
        # check if today's date is within one year from subscriber creation
        # if not set status to expired and redirect to expired-page
        unless (subscriber.created_at..(subscriber.created_at + 1.year)).cover?(Date.today)
          subscriber.update_attributes(:status => "expired")
          redirect_to :expired_path
        end

      when "expired" then
        redirect_to :expired_path
      end
    end
  end

end
```

---

3) Add an `expired` action to subscribers controller. Also, add populate `subscriber.status` with `"subscribed"` in create action.

```
# app/controllers/subscribers_controller.rb
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

  def expired
    render :text => "if the year is up your subscription is now turned off until renewal"
  end

  # […]    

  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)
    @subscriber.status = 'subscribed'

    if @subscriber.save
      flash[:notice] = "Subscriber Has Been Successfully Created"
      redirect_to new_subscriber_path(:subscriber)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
end
```